# LXDE customize main menu add SEARCH BOX like in KDE Kickoff or Windows 7/Vista

Tags: search, lxde, menu

When you open the main menu in say MS Windows (7/Vista) you can quickly search for any item (apps/docs etc.) the same in Ubuntu (Dash), Kubuntu (Kickoff menu).

Is there any easy way to add such a search input which can filter apps (at least just apps no need for docs) in LXDE's main menu?

I Google'd a lot with no success, that's why I'm here.

I am a technical person so if you can give even more low level guide's would help (may be I should create some widget custom panel etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Under lxde, I like to use xfce4-appfinder package.

This xfce package requires one or two xfce libraries, it is only 180kbytes, and will provide you with a search application identical to the one used by xfce: http://jeromeg.blog.free.fr/public/design-sig/appfinder-expanded.png

You should see this application finder in your lxde applications menu. I prefer to add this item in my bottom panel as a launcher.

PS: You can also run it from command line using xfce4-appfinder

Comment: Welcome! Yes, this solutions has saved my day a lot of times...

Answer (score 0):

This seems not possible easily.

But you can write LXPANEL plugins.

http://wiki.lxde.org/en/How_to_write_plugins_for_LXPanel

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is there a possible solution for `lxpanel`, but you can have a menu like that with [Whisker Menu](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin) in Xfce panel. Just install the package `xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin` then start `xfce4-panel` and add Whisker Menu. The package depends on some Xfce's packages, but I guess they worth it.